# Are there any good tutorials for creating Graphviz Diagrams on the mac?

Tags: macos, visualization, graphviz, diagramming

I am pretty interested in Graphviz after I could not find any other useful diagramming tool for the mac.

Are there any good tutorials for creating Graphviz Diagrams on the mac?

Comment: Walk through making digraph ([directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph)) text files with [this brief tutorial](http://www.orient-lodge.com/node/3408). After making the digraph text file, open it with [Graphviz](http://www.pixelglow.com/graphviz/) to render it into an image file.

Comment: I find [the documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info) very helpful.

Comment: [This](http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/media/uml-diagrams-using-graphviz-dot.php) got me started.

Comment: The examples are probably going to be more helpful than anything else in getting those "how do you..." questions answered. On another note - have you looked at OmniGraffle for diagramming? It's my go-to substitute for MacDraw (am I showing my age here?).

Comment: This is  a good place to get your feet wet http://www.webgraphviz.com/. It's an online editor and has some samples.  The doc's good, but anything graphviz takes some patience to get used to if you're not familiar with this kinda stuff - don't give up too quickly, it is very useful once you know it.